# What is the difference between a primary key and an index when it comes to inserting records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, indexing, primary-key

I have to insert data into a table that has a PK in it. I also have another table that has a clustered index in it.

Should I drop the PK or the INDEX for the the best `INSERT` speeds? Then recreate them afterwards?

I load data to these types of tables on a routine basis and I want to make sure I am using the quickest way possible in all situations.

Comment: **NO!** Don't drop the primary key and/or clustered index - that would cause a **major reshuffle** of all your data in the table! Don't do that! Just insert your data - use e.g. `BULK INSERT` or `SqlBulkCopy` to speed things up ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Primary Key and unique key constraint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820213/what-is-the-difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key-constraint)

Comment: Not a duplicate issue...he was asking the difference between the two I want to know how each impact inserting of records...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primary key uniquely identifies a record and has other uses as well.  An index makes select queries run faster.

You should never drop your primary key.

Whether or not you drop and re-create indexes when adding records depends on the circumstances.

Comment: The circmstances are the table is trunated and replaced each day.

Answer (score 0):

**Primary Key :** Uniquely identifies the the data & we cannot insert duplicate Data.

**Index** : Index help us to get out data to us very quickly.

### Very Important Concept about Primary key & Index

Suppose your column is marked with the primary key then Clustered Index automatically  gets created,
If no clutstered index is already present in the table

To See that Your Index is Created Successfully, You can use.

```
sp_helpindex Index_Name
```

**- About Index :**

You cannot create a unique index on a single column if that column contains NULL in more than one row. Similarly, you cannot create a unique index on multiple columns if the combination of columns contains NULL in more than one row. These are treated as duplicate values for indexing purposes.

**- About Primary Key :**

All columns defined within a PRIMARY KEY constraint must be defined as NOT NULL. If nullability is not specified, all columns participating in a PRIMARY KEY constraint have their nullability set to NOT NULL.

Comment: This does not address my question...when can I get faster load speeds by dropping the index/pk?